# UIScrollView in iOS 6

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiscrollview, ios6

Recently i've downloaded Xcode 4.5(iOS 6),but when tried to continue one of my projects i noticed that the UIScrollView isn't working properly,let me explain more clearly:

I've created the UIScrollView and added the initialized it using the following code:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

    [mainScrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    mainScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(480, 0);

    [super viewDidLoad];

}
```

After i opened my XIB and linked the `mainScrollView` to a UIScrollView,after i added some UIButton's to the scrollView.When i built the project the `mainScrollView` was scrolling but the buttons didn't showed up,i mean,i just could see the button that were already on the screen.**What i'm doing wrong?How can i setup the UIScrollView?**

Comment: I had the same problem just now. Could this be a bug in the iOS6 SDK?

Answer (score 39):

For `xcode 4.5` ,If you are using `scrollView` you have to either uncheck "`use AutoLayout`" in file inspector.

or if you want to "use `AutoLayout`",then in **.m(implementation) file** add this

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    theScroller.contentSize=CGSizeMake(1024.0,1300.0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you!! Banging my head against a brick wall for a hour or more with this. Again, thank you.

Comment: OK, so the answer for AutoLayout is found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12619786/embed-imageview-in-scrollview-with-auto-layout-on-ios-6 basically, move the `contentSize` code to the `viewDidAppear` method.

Comment: THANK YOU for this post!!!!  I have literally burned an entire day with this.  I unchecked "use AutoLayout" and finally my scrollView works like its supposed to.  Burns me up...  TY again

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you just typed this wrong, but your `CGSize` has a height of 0?

Comment: Just to disable the vertical scrolling!

Comment: Can't you just disable it in IB? Or just using properties? Setting the CGSize width to 0 sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: If you want to disable vertical scrolling, set the content height to the same as the size of the scroll view and turn off vertical bouncing.

Comment: Both ways work,but my problem id different!Is like,when i scroll the UIButton's remain inert,like they aren't inside the UIScrollView,like the are inside the main view!

Comment: Why don't you try logging the buttons' superviews?

Comment: Ok i've logged the superview and i got this result:<UIScrollView: 0x7a70aa0; frame = (0 20; 320 128); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+TM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7a7c420>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7a70c90>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with Auto Layout in XCode 4.5
But you config your UIScrollView in viewDidAppear

I do this also in a static UITableView with images.

Name your images like timg1.png, timg2.png....

in your ControllerView.h File

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *Sv1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPageControl *Pc1;
```

In your ControllerView.m File

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    //Scrollview
    Sv1.delegate = self;

    Sv1.contentSize = CGSizeMake(260, 176);

    [self.Sv1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    // ScrollViewGarten.frame = CGRectMake(9, 11, 283, 170);
    [Sv1 setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];

    Sv1.multipleTouchEnabled = NO;
    Sv1.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
    Sv1.clipsToBounds = YES;
    Sv1.scrollEnabled = YES;
    Sv1.pagingEnabled = YES;

    NSUInteger nimagesTextil = 0;
    CGFloat cxTextil = 0;
    for (; ; nimagesTextil++) {
        NSString *imageNameTextil = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"timg%d.png", (nimagesTextil + 1)];
        UIImage *imageTextil = [UIImage imageNamed:imageNameTextil];
        if (imageTextil == nil) {
            break;
        }
        UIImageView *imageViewTextil = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imageTextil];

        CGRect rect = imageViewTextil.frame;
        rect.size.height = 176;
        rect.size.width = 260;
        rect.origin.x = ((Sv1.frame.size.width - imageTextil.size.width) / 2) + cxTextil;
        rect.origin.y = ((Sv1.frame.size.height - imageTextil.size.height) / 2);

        imageViewTextil.frame = rect;

        [Sv1 addSubview:imageViewTextil];

        cxTextil += Sv1.frame.size.width;
    }
    self.Pc1.numberOfPages = nimagesTextil;
    [Sv1 setContentSize:CGSizeMake(cxTextil, [Sv1 bounds].size.height)];
    self.Pc1.currentPage = 0;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is a bug with either Xcode 4.5 or the iOS 6 SDK. The way I fixed it was by adding the subviews to my UIScrollView programatically.

So you would have to do something like:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(400.0f, 10.0f, 60.0f, 30.0f);
    [mainScrollView addSubView:button];
    mainScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(480.0f, mainScrollView.frame.size.height);
}
```

Try this and let me know if this worked for you.

If you have an old version of Xcode it might be a good idea to replicate the code and the nib over there to see the results.

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to fix this AND use AutoLayout, move your `contentSize` code to the `viewDidAppear` method. I found the answer in this SO question: [Embed ImageView in ScrollView with Auto Layout on iOS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12619786/embed-imageview-in-scrollview-with-auto-layout-on-ios-6)

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
[self.scrollview setScrollEnabled:YES];
[self.scrollview setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[self.scrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, _y)];
[self.scrollview setAlwaysBounceVertical:YES];
}
```

I use the class variable _y since I add all the subviews heights to it.