# UIScrollView and Autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

i have the following Storyboard as shown:

[image: storyboard overview]

i am trying to get my UIScrollview to scroll. I had it working perfectly without Auto Layout, but it doesn't appear to be working now I've turned Auto Layout on.

I've been following this blog post: [How to make a ScrollView with AutoLayout in Xcode5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19112189/how-to-make-a-scrollview-with-autolayout-in-xcode5)

but the scroll still refuses to work, and i get warnings in relation to ambiguous scroll position (see image below)

[image]

can somebody please explain how to set up UIScrollView with auto layout, including the properties of the embedded views (lengths etc)

Comment: This may help you:

 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499467/uiscrollview-doesnt-use-autolayout-constraints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use autolayout with scroll view, you have to follow these rules:

1 Make sure your scroll view frame can be calculated:

1.1 You have to setup leading, top, trailing, bottom constrains of it to parent view.

1.2 Or you can setup x, y position of it (leading and top constraints for example) and width and height constrains.

2 View (or views) frame inside scroll view also should be possible to calculate:

2.1 Make sure that view inside scroll view has leading, top, trailing and bottom constraints **and** width and height constrains.

2.2 If your view's frame size should be calculated with frames of items in this view, you need:

2.2.1 For this view (inside scroll) setup leading, top, trailing, bottom constraints to scroll view.

2.2.2 For each item in this view setup explicit frame (leading, top, trailing, bottom, width, height constraints).

Comment: can you pleas explain this in terms of the layout i have (i.e., the constraints for each of my views, and the scroll view. following the steps above still does not yield a scrolling view.

Comment: Would you provide an example project? This question is asked very often and i think, a real example would be very helpfully to the community