# UIScrollView not scrolling from objects inside

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a scrollview which contains a view and 3 subviews inside of this view  (topview, textview and bottomview). See the view's hierachy below. The scrollview is scrollable only if I scroll it from the textview but not from any other area. What am I doing wrong? All views have user interaction enabled.

EDIT: 
I have realized if User Interaction is disabled in the containerview I can scroll from any place in the view but since I have buttons inside my container view I want user interaction and scrolling, is that possible?

[image]

This is the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //update labels and images with info
    self.TitleLabel.text = game.title;
    self.SubtitleLabel.text = game.developer;
    self.DescriptionTextView.text = game.description;
    self.Screenshot.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:game.pictData];
}

-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self.mainScrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [self.mainScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 1200)];
}

-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    NSAttributedString * string = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.game.description];
    CGFloat heightTV = [self textViewHeightForAttributedText:string andWidth:260];
    self.dynamicTVHeight.constant = heightTV;
    self.dynamicContainerHeight.constant = self.topView.frame.size.height + heightTV + self.bottomView.frame.size.height+100;
    NSLog(@"height container %f", self.dynamicContainerHeight.constant);
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}

- (CGFloat)textViewHeightForAttributedText:(NSAttributedString *)text andWidth:(CGFloat)width
{
    UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
    [textView setAttributedText:text];
    CGSize size = [textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(width, FLT_MAX)];
    return size.height;
}
```

Comment: Are you setting UIScrollView's content size properly?

Comment: Yes. And it scrolls down if I scroll it from the textview.

Comment: Uhm, maybe seeing some code could help to understand the problem. 
The Text View itself is scrollable. When you say that it scrolls in the textview, could happen that is the TextView that scrolls instead of the UIScrollView. Can you verify that?

Comment: the textview is not scrollable. It scrolls the UISCrollView.

Comment: code you upload the code, and we can download and debug.

Comment: the code is the same. I disabled the user interaction from Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but your problem seems with AutoLayout, you can try this 
[How to make a ScrollView with AutoLayout in Xcode5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19112189/how-to-make-a-scrollview-with-autolayout-in-xcode5/22191295#22191295)

It solved similar problem for me.