# UIScrollView not scrolling after setting content size

Tags: uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView and I'm setting the frame size smaller than the Content size, and it still won't scroll.  I've tried searching a lot of questions on here but each time it's usually the person wasn't setting -(void)setContentSize:(CGSize)size.  I'm also calling it on -(void)viewDidLoad so not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Here is my code:

```
self.theScrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
self.theScrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
self.theScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0,19,320,434);
self.theScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(322, 900);
```

Any help?  Thanks.

Comment: I'm stupid, had to uncheck Autolayout in File Inspector:  [Link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182008/uiscrollview-in-ios-6